# Why is there no GraphFrames release for Spark 2.4.x and scala 2.12?

Tags: apache-spark, graphframes

I'm looking at the graphframes releases available here: https://spark-packages.org/package/graphframes/graphframes. The only GraphFrames release available for scala 2.12 as of April 22 2020 is with Spark 3.0, but Spark 3.0 isn't production yet. Is there a reason why there wouldn't be a release that works with Spark 2.4.x and scala 2.12?